# XYPieChart and iOS 6.x and CALayerInvalidGeometry

Tags: objective-c, xcode, inversion-of-control, calayer

i create a Pie chart like this:

```
NSArray *n = [data allKeys];

long sc = [n count];

XYPieChart *pie = [[XYPieChart alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.pieStart, 160, 220)];
[pie setDataSource:self];
[pie setDelegate:self];
[pie setStartPieAngle:M_PI_2];
[pie setAnimationSpeed:1.0];
[pie setLabelFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:11]];
[pie setLabelRadius:40];
[pie setShowPercentage:NO];
[pie setPieBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.95 alpha:1]];
[pie setPieCenter:CGPointMake(80, 100)];
[pie setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
[pie setLabelShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
pie.tag = tag;

pie.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

UILabel *t = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 2, 320, 21)];
t.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[t setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:17]];
t.text = title;

UILabel *p = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(71, 90, 18, 18)];
p.text = @"%";
p.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
p.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[p setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:13]];
p.layer.cornerRadius = 9;
p.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

int vc = 35;
int lc = 31;

[pie addSubview:t];
[pie addSubview:p];

[self.myScroll addSubview:pie];

self.pieStart += 220;

[pie reloadData];

for(int i = 0; i < sc; i++){

    UIView *cc = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(162, vc, 9, 9)];
    cc.backgroundColor = [self.sliceColors objectAtIndex:(i % self.sliceColors.count)];
    [pie addSubview:cc];

    UILabel *tl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(180, lc, 134, 17)];
    [tl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10]];
    tl.text = [self.ss objectAtIndex:i];
    [pie addSubview:tl];

    vc += 12;
    lc += 12;

}

//NSLog(@"got here");

UIView *line = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, pie.frame.size.height - 20, 320, 1)];
line.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

[pie addSubview:line];
```

and try to set a custom slice label like this:

```
-(NSString *)pieChart:(XYPieChart *)pieChart textForSliceAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

{

```
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.slices objectAtIndex:index]];
```

}

but i get this in return:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer bounds contains NaN: [-1.99794 0; 1.99794 nan]'
```

*** First throw call stack:
(0x1625012 0x144ae7e 0x1624deb 0x29fa75 0x29fd1e 0x2f6e6 0x2b54f 0x1378e 0xf0a8 0xe3a4 0x10ad417 0x10c6b24 0x107bd60 0x10c86ad 0xbf1d 0x6991c7 0x699232 0x6994da 0x6b08e5 0x6b09cb 0x6b0c76 0x6b0d71 0x6b189b 0x6b1e93 0x6b1a88 0xa0de63 0x9ffb99 0x9ffc14 0x145e705 0x5bb2c0 0x7f7a64 0x145e705 0x5bb2c0 0x5bb258 0x67c021 0x67c57f 0x67b6e8 0x5eacef 0x5eaf02 0x5c8d4a 0x5ba698 0x2adadf9 0x2adaad0 0x159abf5 0x159a962 0x15cbbb6 0x15caf44 0x15cae1b 0x2ad97e3 0x2ad9668 0x5b7ffc 0x43a6d 0x27fb701)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

so far I've been able to figure out that the error occurs when the [pie reloadData] happens.

It works perfectly fine with iOS7

is there a setting that I'm not applying or did i do something wrong?

On my last project i used XYPieCharts also and i supported iOS 6 also, the only difference was that i created the UIView with the pie chart in the IB creator instead of in code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out!

Its a bug in the iOS 6.1 simulator. The actual device does not crash.

Also the problem stemmed from `updateLabelForLayer`

the check was not made if the layer responded to selector `sizeWithAttributes:`

looks like the file has been tempered with and after fixing that issue it worked.